# Set first_name, last_name and email from User model as default value in field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to set default values for `first_name`, `lastname` and `email` in my model

Got the following model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Project(models.Model):
        firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name=_("label_general_firstname"), default=User.first_name)
        lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name=_("label_general_lastname"), default=User.last_name)
        email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name=_("label_general_email"), default=User.email)
```

When running the migration, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f459e8aac50>
```

I got users coming in via an SSO, and they already have certain fields filled out.
I want to use these as default values when using a form which uses this model.

Have tried several ways, but never got a working result.

**Edit:**

This is how I understand the workflow from this app:

In `projects/urls.py` I see the following

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',
        login_required(PermCheckUpdateView.as_view(
            model = Project,
            form_class = ProjectGeneralForm,
            template_name = "project/general.html",
            success_url = "/projects/{id}")),
        name = "project_update_general"),
```

So the `PermCheckUpdateView` view seems to be rendering the form

in `app/views.py` I can see the view like this:

```
class PermCheckUpdateView(ObjectPermCheckMixin,CallableSuccessUrlMixin,UpdateView):
    # make the form readonly if its only readable
    def get_form(self):
        form = super(PermCheckUpdateView, self).get_form()

        if not self.object.has_write_permission(self.request.user) and not self.request.user.is_staff:
            for field in form.fields.values():
                field.widget.attrs["readonly"] = "readonly"
            if hasattr(form,"helper"):
                form.helper.inputs = []
        return form
```

Going back, this is `ObjectPermCheckMixin`

```
class ObjectPermCheckMixin(ObjectPermCheckGETMixin, ObjectPermCheckPOSTMixin):
    pass
```

And both `ObjectPermCheckGETMixin` and `ObjectPermCheckPOSTMixin`

```
class ObjectPermCheckGETMixin(object):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.object.has_read_permission(self.request.user) and not request.user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(ObjectPermCheckGETMixin, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class ObjectPermCheckPOSTMixin(object):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if not self.object.has_write_permission(self.request.user) and not request.user.is_staff:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(ObjectPermCheckPOSTMixin, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I tried to set the request.user in both of them, but failed so far.
One of the errors was that `__init__` required 2 inputs, but only one was given.

I don't know Django that much to solve this on my own.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can not do that, in this model, there is not even a (related) `User`. This is something the form, view, etc. should carry out.

Comment: Tried to get to the user object in the forms as well, got a different issue there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545946/retrieve-user-object-from-username

Answer (score 0):

The `default`s are either a real value, or a callable (without parameter) that generates a value at runtime (for example depending on the settings, database queries, timestamp, etc.)

If the default of a field depends on other fields, you can override the `.save(..)` function, but even that is not really advisable, since the `.save(..)` function can be circumented (in case of a bulk insert, etc.).

Since here the `User` is not stored on the project, it should be handled in the `Form` or view. For example:

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def __init__(*args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user and self.instance.pk is None:  # new item constructed
            self.instance.firstname = user.first_name
            self.instance.lastname = user.last_name
```

If you then construct such form in a view, you need to pass `request.user` as *named* parameter:

```
def some_view(request):
    form = MyForm(user=request.user)
    # ...
```

Note however that if the `firstname` and `lastname` depend on a `User`, you better add a `ForeignKey` to the `User`. Since otherwise you introduce *data duplication*.

Comment: I found this approach several times. The problem with that is that in this case there is no view which generates the form. The form is being rendered from a single template variable.

Comment: @derchris: but templates do not *construct* forms, they only render it, so that means that a view, implicitly or explicitly, has constructed the form.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the view. But the form construction looks very different. I'm trying to get this implemented in a working project, so not my code.

Comment: @derchris: can you edit your question and share (relevant parts of) the view?